# Cannot bind Transmission (or any other app) to local IP when connected to VPN

Tags: transmission, pptp, bind

I want all my applications to use VPN connection except for Transmission, which I want to use my eth0 interface. But when I set `"bind-address-ipv4":"192.168.250.2"` in the `settings.jason` , Transmission couldn't connect to any peer.

I also found out that I can't bind any application to local network interface when the VPN is connected, for example:

When the VPN is not connected:

```
$ ping -I 192.168.250.2 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.250.2 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=44 time=229 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=44 time=229 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=44 time=229 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=44 time=227 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=5 ttl=44 time=226 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 226.323/228.578/229.797/1.332 ms
```

When the VPN is connected:

```
$ ping -I 192.168.250.2 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.250.2 : 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
133 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 132177ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get things right following [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/228195/answering-on-the-same-interface-where-the-request-came-from) on serverfault.

I just added these ip routing rules and everything went fine:

```
$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.250.1 dev eth0 table 10
$ sudo ip rule add from 192.168.250.2 table 10
```